# How can I make the grid gap cascade through shadow DOM [LitElements]

Tags: css-grid, web-component, lit-element, lit-html, native-web-component

I am building a web app using web components in LitElement.js. I have a div containing most components (let's call it `.top`) that specifies a grid layout and a background image. In the div I have a custom component (call it `<custom-container>` that is itself composed of custom components (call each instance `<custom-leaf>`). The container also uses `display: grid` and defines a `grid-column-gap`.

The problem: between each `<custom-leaf>` nested inside the `<custom-container>` there is a grid gap, however, it is invisible: instead of "piercing" through the background image, it shows the background image.

Here is some code:

`index.html`

```html
<style>
     .top {
         grid-gap: 4px;
         display: grid;
         background-image: url("../img/background.jpg");
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div class="top">
        <custom-container></custom-container>
    </div>
    <script src="customContainer.js"/>
    <script src="customLeaf.js"/>
</body>
```

`customContainer.js`

```js
class CustomContainer extends LitElement {
    static get styles() {
        return css`
             :host {
                 display: grid;
                 grid-gap: 4px
             }
        `
    }

    render() {
        return html`<custom-leaf></custom-leaf><custom-leaf></custom-leaf>`
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the complete code to try to reproduce the error? I think it may be a CSS adjustment

Comment: Strictly speaking your are not doing *Vanilla JS* as you say in the first line. Using Lit is like using jQuery. You use the library, the library creates the Custom Element/Web Component.

Comment: I am happy to add more code @HerberthObregon, I just don't want to cloud the code with unrelated styling (e.g., color etc). I don't have any more code governing positioning.